# Why should I specify a use statement when using the say function?

Tags: perl

This question may be stupid. But I just started exploring Perl. I am using Perl v5.16.2. I know that the `say` statement has been introduced in 5.10.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

say "Hello World!";
```

When I try to run above program, I am getting the following error:

```
$ ./helloPerl 
String found where operator expected at ./helloPerl line 3, near "say "Hello World!""
    (Do you need to predeclare say?)
syntax error at ./helloPerl line 3, near "say "Hello World!""
Execution of ./helloPerl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

But when I added the statement `use 5.016;`, it is giving me the correct output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.016;
say "Hello World!";
```

My doubt is, I am using perl v5.16.2, which is above 5.010. Why should I mention the Perl version using a `use` statement here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Features that might break backwards compatibility, aren't enabled by default.

See [`perldoc feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html):

> It is usually impossible to add new syntax to Perl without breaking some existing programs. This pragma provides a way to minimize that risk. New syntactic constructs, or new semantic meanings to older constructs, can be enabled by use feature 'foo' , and will be parsed only when the appropriate feature pragma is in scope. (Nevertheless, the CORE:: prefix provides access to all Perl keywords, regardless of this pragma.)

`use` on a version number, implicitly enables all features, because it also applies a constraint on perl version. So you won't be tripped over by `say` not being implemented, for example.

Comment: I would like to point out that some features that were syntax errors previously may not need a `use` statement to enable.

Comment: I take it you mean like `s/pattern/newpattern/r` and `$var // 0`  type things? Yes, that's correct. They're not going to break backwards compatibility. You can still enforce a minimum perl version though via `use` (and probably should if you're doing something that's version dependent)

Answer (score 16):

`say` is a **feature**, it's not (yet - will it ever be?) regular perl syntax.

Use either

```
use feature qw(say);
```

or

```
use v5.010; # or any version later
```

Comment: I don't think it ever will be, simply because it's a backwards compatibility and design question. Historically, perl hasn't invalidated previously 'good' code, which is why e.g. `strict` and `warnings` are optional, despite being a REALLY good idea.